# How to remove GCC warning on #pragma region?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, gcc

How to remove GCC warning on `#pragma region` ?
I added `pragma region` to easily look at code but it reports warnings on `#pragma region`.
I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: are you compiling with GCC in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Possibly useful reading: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/SuppressingGCCWarnings.html

Comment: My suggestion: Refactor the code. Turn the region into separate function(s).

Answer (score 17):

gcc has this warning flag:

> **-Wunknown-pragmas**
>              Warn when a #pragma directive is encountered which is not understood by GCC.  If this command line option is used, warnings will
>   even be issued for unknown pragmas in system header files.  This is
>   not
>              the case if the warnings were only enabled by the -Wall command line option.

And as per usual you can negate it, meaning unknown pragmas will not be given a warning. That is, use `-Wno-unknown-pragmas`.

Note that `-Wno-unknown-pragmas` must come after any command line flags that turn on this warning, such as `-Wall` - this also disables warnings on all unknown pragmas, so use with care.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, this option turns off warnings for _all_ pragmas, it's not possible to pick and choose which pragmas should generate warnings and which should not.

Comment: Yes, @JoachimPileborg, and this diagnostic (`unknown-pragmas`) can sometimes be life-saving, if you mess up with `omp` pragmas or the like...

Answer (score 12):

Don't use it on GCC? :)

The simplest solution I can think of at the moment is to use the preprocessor conditionals for it:

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#pragma region
#endif

// Stuff...

#ifndef __GNUC__
#pragma endregion
#endif
```

Not very good looking or readable, but will make the code compile without warnings on GCC.

Comment: @altendky I'm not sure about it, as it's used by the Visual Studio editor to denote regions that can be folded. It depends on how good the Visual Studio editor parser is.

Comment: @altendky - How? a single `#` (as opposed to `##`) inside a macro's *replacement-list* does not identify a preprocessor directive. It is instead the stringify operator. The thing following the `#` operator must be a macro parameter name.

Comment: If MSVC supports the C99 and C++11 `_Pragma` operator you could conditionally define a macro to `_Pragma("region")` when using MSVC and define it to nothing otherwise

Comment: Bad idea.  When I wrap stuff in a region its so I can collapse it and move it around in the file and keep everything in the region together.  Thats kind of the whole point.  Wrapping it menas moving it would leave behind little bits of #ifndef and #endif code everywhere and turn into a huge mess.

Answer (score 5):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
... Code using Unknown pragmas ...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Since you're also building on Windows you probably want to wrap this in: #ifdef __GNUC__

Comment: This would be the best answer if it weren't for this bug:  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431 .  As it is, it seems the workaround is the nuclear option that just disables the warnings for unknown pragmas:  -Wno-unknown-pragmas on the command line.  The ultimate right answer is for GCC to acknowledge & properly handle regions: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=85487 .

Comment: @Jimbo1987 Well, it seems like it's fixed recently. But of course it won't work in most of the current GCC versions, but over time it will be worth considering again. For now I'm going with "-Wno-unknown-pragmas". For my code it's sufficient, for enterprise not really.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a MSVC specific pragma, so you should use

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma region
#endif

<code here>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma endregion
#endif
```

Comment: But then you can't collapse between ```pragma``` regions!

Answer (score 3):

`#pragma region` support in compilers has improved since this question was asked. The following table lists compilers supporting this feature:

| compiler | supported since |
| --- | --- |
| msvc | unknown since when this is supported |
| icc | unknown since when this is supported |
| clang | >= version 6 on all targets (earlier versions already support it on windows) |
| gcc | >= version 13 (bug [85487](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85487)) |

Comment: spell out the answer. you're telling them to update their compiler. give exact version numbers including for clang if you're going to make a point about it.

Comment: I added some more info, but I am unsure when exactly some compilers added support for this feature. Feel free to complete the table :)

Comment: nice update. links to "official" writing on info would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment the `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion` lines, your editor might still be able to parse it and use the folding feature without gcc emitting any warnings.

I have tested it on VSCode 1.70.2 and this workaround works.

[image]